# Is there a name for this pattern with closures?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, groovy, closures, terminology

I often see a pattern used in circumstances where we have look-up code that needs to be executed before we have access to an object. When using this pattern, usually begins with the word `with`.

For example, we have customer records that need to be retrieved from a database before we can use them:

```
def withCustomer (id, closure) {
    def customer = getCustomer(id)
    closure(customer)
}

withCustomer(12345) { customer ->
    println "Found customer $customer.name"
}
```

Groovy makes no such distinction between closures or anonymous functions. Perhaps, I could ask if there is a name for this pattern with anonymous functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Strategy pattern. The closure holds some piece of behavior to be passed into the function as an argument, so that the function can accept different behaviors. See Peter Norvig's presentation [Design Patterns in Dynamic Languages](http://norvig.com/design-patterns/ppframe.htm):

> The strategy is a variable whose value is a function (E.g., with
>   first-class functions, pattern is invisible)

Comment: What do you think about [@mgryszko answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10093625/462015)

Comment: @Arturo: i had thought of template method as necessarily involving inheritance, where strategy was an alternative to it, not a form of it. http://tech.puredanger.com/2007/07/03/pattern-hate-template/

Comment: What do you think about [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10306434/462015)?

Comment: @Arturo: just now saw that. I was not aware of that, voted it up.

Answer (score 2):

In Groovy's [Closures - Formal Definition](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures+-+Formal+Definition) it is just called "**Passing Closures to Methods**".

Groovy has a special case for defining closures as method arguments to make the closure syntax easier to read. Specifically, if the last argument of a method is of type Closure, you may invoke the method with an explicit closure block outside of the parenthesis. For example, if a class has a method:

```
class SomeCollection {
    public void each ( Closure c )
}
```

Then you may invoke each() with a closure definition outside of the parenthesis:

```
SomeCollection stuff = new SomeCollection();
stuff.each() { println it }
```

The more traditional syntax is also available, and also note that in Groovy you can elide parenthesis in many situations, so these two variations are also legal:

```
SomeCollection stuff = new SomeCollection();

stuff.each { println it }       // Look ma, no parens
stuff.each ( { println it } )   // Strictly traditional
```

The same rule applies even if the method has other arguments. The only restriction is that the Closure argument must be last:

```
class SomeCollection {
  public void inject ( x, Closure c )
}

stuff.inject( 0 ) { count, item -> count + item  }     // Groovy
stuff.inject( 0, { count, item -> count + item  } )    // Traditional
```

---

That may not be relevant to the "Groovy question", but for example in Scala, this "form" is a special case of **function currying**:

```
scala> def fun[A, B](a: A)(b: B) = {true}
fun: [A, B](a: A)(b: B)Boolean

scala> fun(1){2}
res59: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you don't ask my question. I asked the name of this pattern, not the use of closures.

Comment: this is not a pattern, but a syntax form, and the name for this syntax form in Groovy is "**Passing Closures to Methods**". If you want to be closer to the word "pattern", an example in Scala is "**function currying**" (although there is much more that you can do with Scala's function currying than this syntax form, but it just happens to be one of the special cases).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. It can be a Strategy pattern (see Nathan Hughes' answer). It can be a Template Method pattern.

Arturo's example seems to be a Template Method. You define common algorithm steps (getting a customer in this case) and customizations (passed as a closure).

Comment: What do you think about [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10306434/462015)?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I think that this pattern is called **Loan Pattern**.

Loan Pattern, ensures that a resource is deterministically disposed of once it goes out of scope.

You can see some information about this pattern here:

- ['Loan' pattern](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Loan) - Scala
- [Loan my Resource Pattern](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Loan+my+Resource+Pattern) - Groovy